# Kicking clients from TCP server

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, server

I tried to add a functionality to my server to kick specific clients. But `Read` function in client's thread is blocking the loop and client's kicked command won't be executed until client sends an another message. So I added this to client's thread in server; (By the way, I can't really understand why I should put `Poll` there but it throws an error without it.)

```
if (client.Socket.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    readMessageSize = client.Stream.Read(readMessage, 0, _packetSize); 
}
else
{
    if (client.Kicked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The client [" + client.IP + "] has been kicked.");
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(10);
    continue;
}
```

This time, it gives an error on client's constructor (this constructor takes the socket that returns from `Accept()` function as parameter) says: "The operation is not allowed on a non-blocking Socket.". So, I set Blocking true temporarily like this;

```
public ClientSocket(Socket client)
{
    _socket = client;
    _socket.Blocking = true;

    try
    {
        Stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    _socket.Blocking = false;
}
```

I also set listener socket's Blocking to false and changed it because when I tried to `Abort()` listener thread it won't, because it's stucked at `Accept()`.

```
while (Running)
{
    try
    {
        if (_socket.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            var newClientSocket = _socket.Accept();
            AddClient(newClientSocket);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        StopListen();
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

I feel like I'm going a wrong way implemeting the server. I'm ready to listen any advice. I can also accept any open source projects or code snippets which might help me with this.

Comment: If you're going to have a thread to block trying to read from the client, don't have that thread do anything else. Do the kicking on another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the code you posted:

1. Don't switch a socket back and forth between blocking and non-blocking. If .NET doesn't want a non-blocking socket for a `NetworkStream` object, setting a socket you've given to a `NetworkStream` to non-blocking later is just going to cause problems.
2. You won't need to use the `Socket.Poll()` method to do this correctly, but it's very important to note that there's a difference between "microseconds" (used in the `Poll()` method) and "milliseconds" (used almost everywhere else in .NET for integer time intervals). Maybe you really mean to wait only 10 microseconds in the `Poll()` method, but it's not entirely clear from your post what you meant to do, so I want to make sure you're aware of the difference.

As far as the right way to do this goes:

1. The first thing to do is to implement a non-blocking server, but to do it correctly. Use one of the asynchronous API options. Since you are using `NetworkStream`, the most obvious approach would be to use the `ReadAsync()` method.
2. Having implemented a non-blocking server, then terminating a client connection is as simple as maintaining the timeout logic somewhere (you won't be blocking a thread with I/O, but that also means you don't have an I/O thread you can use for the timeout…you'll have to put that timeout logic somewhere else).
3. Ideally, you will "terminate" the client with a graceful closure, i.e. calling the `Socket.Shutdown()` method, waiting for the client to close its end (i.e. you see a receive operation complete with 0-byte length). But you can probably get away with resetting the connection if you must (i.e. `Socket.Close()`). Either will cause the asynchronous read operation to complete, allowing you to clean up the client information.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Yes, I noticed it's microseconds but I didn't really think about it, only gave a random number to it. And without poll, it gives an error: "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.".

Do I have to use async functions? I want to do this in that way.

Comment: @Cem: No, you don't _have_ to use async functions. But it would be far simpler, and accomplish the same result. If you are going to use non-blocking sockets, you need to learn how to use them. In particular, I'm reasonably sure the error you got is normal for a non-blocking socket, corresponding to the Winsock error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. Rather than calling `Poll()`, you're expect to just "try again later". Normally you'd use the `Socket.Select()` method to determine when to try again (i.e. you still wind up with a thread blocking, but on more than one socket), rather than looping with `Poll()`.

Comment: @Cem: And to be clear, while I'm positive you can get this to work with non-blocking sockets, it is my _opinion_ that doing it that way is wrong. The non-blocking feature is inherited from the Winsock API, which in turn is inherited from the more general socket API. Windows has a much better asynchronous model to use, which is more efficient _and_ easier to code for. Non-blocking mode is really only there for compatibility, and is not an appropriate way to implement new code on Windows.

Comment: I can't understand the "try again later" part. Select() seemes like it has the same functionality as Poll(). What difference will it make to use Select()? 

From your second comment, I interpret that; .NET doesn't have appropriate tools to implement with this manner. Did I get this right?

Comment: @Cem: No, I don't think you got this precisely right. You _can_ implement this in .NET this way if you really insist. But the implementation will be significantly inferior to an implementation that uses async I/O instead of non-blocking mode. `Select()` is not exactly the same as `Poll()`: `Select()` allows a single thread to monitor multiple sockets, which is important in Windows, because threads are very costly OS objects (which is not the case in Unix, where the sockets API originated). With `Poll()` you are forced to have a whole thread committed to each connection, restricting scalability